# Nested directive life-cycle not executing in expected order when using $compile and adding to the DOM for the first time

Tags: angularjs

## What I'm trying to do

I have the following directive structure:

```
<dashboard>
    <widget>
        <timer></timer>
    </widget>
    <widget>
        <chronometer></chronometer>
    </widget>
</dashboard>
```

Where `dashboard`, `widget`, `timer`, and `chronometer` are all custom directives that I've written.

The basic idea is that I want the `dashboard` directive to keep track of all the `widgets` that it has. When a `widget` is `$compile`d and added to the DOM from the `dashboard`, it automatically adds itself to the `dashboard` by calling an `addWidget(widget)` method from the `widget`'s `link` function, which is exposed by the `dashboard`'s controller.

The `widget` directive knows how to minimize itself, close itself, set its title, etc., and it too has a `register` method on its `controller` that takes in widget metadata information (e.g., the name and version of a widget).

The `timer` and `chronometer` widgets then require `widget` and call the `register({name: 'timer', version: '0.1'})' which exists in the`widget`'s controller function.

Finally, there is an `addWidget()` method in the `dashboard`'s `link` function which allows users to add the `timer` and `chronometer` widgets to the dashboard.

For this example, I'm going to assume we just want to add the `timer` directive to the dashboard:

```
// dashboard.directive.js

function link($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
    $scope.addWidget = function () {
        var widget = $compile('<widget><timer></timer></widget>')($scope);
        angular.element($elem[0].querySelector('.widget-container')).append(widget);
    }
}
```

When the `$addWidget` function is called, the timer widget is successfully added to the dashboard, I can start/stop/reset the timer, and the `widget` directive registers the `timer` directive, and then the `widget` directive registers itself with the `dashboard` directive. I've 100% confirmed that this is working perfectly.

## Directive life-cycle: what I'm expecting

As a reminder, here's how the DOM looks like:

```
<dashboard> <!-- the dashboard already exists on initial bootstrap -->
    <widget> <!-- the widget and timer are added dynamically by the dashboard -->
        <timer></timer>
    </widget>
    <widget> <!-- the widget and chronometer are added dynamically by the dashboard -->
        <chronometer></chronometer>
    </widget>
</dashboard>
```

From what I understand of Angular directives' life-cycle, the directives should be constructed as follows:

```
dashboard controller() called
dashboard link() called

widget controller() called
  timer controller() called
  timer link() called
widget link() called
```

Where the widget and timer are added to the DOM within the `dashboard` as described in the `dashboard.directive.js` snippet above.

## Directive life-cycle: what I'm getting (sometimes)

**However, sometimes when I add the timer to the dashboard for the first time, this is not the case**. After I added a bunch of `console.log` statements inside the `controller` and `link` functions for the `dashboard`, `widget` and `timer` directives, however, I found that the directives are sometimes being constructed in this order:

```
dashboard controller() called
dashboard link() called

// Why is this happening:

  widget controller() called
  widget link() called

  timer controller() called
  timer link() called
```

What's even more puzzling is that this seemingly out-of-order composing only happens the first time I add the widget to the DOM. The second time I add the same widget, everything happens in the correct order.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Angular 1.2.26 (I am required to use that version, unfortunately). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Would it be at all possible for you to setup a Plunk/jsBin so as to showcase the issue further/allow us to debug it?

Comment: Does your `timer` directive retrieve the template asynchronously with `templateUrl`? if so, this would change the order to `post`-link the `widget` first, and then run `controller`/`pre`/`post` on the `timer`. The async behavior remains, however, even after the caching, so the order should *not* change, so your last comment is still a puzzle... so, a plunker/fiddle would help

Comment: isn't this like the right order ? http://assets.toptal.io/uploads/blog/image/611/toptal-blog-image-1412667594404.png